# Wrong number format when creating SLD from YAML via REST API

Tags: geoserver, sld, geoserver-rest-api

In our workflow we are creating style definitions in YAML locally and then upload these styles via GeoServer REST API to the server. A sample YAML file looks like this:

```
name:  Test Style
title: test style description
abstract: Used for testing
feature-styles:
- rules:
 - title: raster
symbolizers:
  - raster:
      opacity: 1.0
      color-map:
        type: values
        entries:
        - ['#e20374', 1.0, 1, lorem ipsum]
```

The creation on the server works fine. However, when we try to apply this style to a layer, we get the following error:

```
2017-03-01 17:40:36,234 INFO [geoserver.wms] - 
Request: getServiceInfo
2017-03-01 17:40:36,240 ERROR [geoserver.ows] - 
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string:"java.awt.Color[r=226,g=3,b=116]"
at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
at java.lang.Integer.valueOf(Integer.java:740)
at java.lang.Integer.decode(Integer.java:1197)
at java.awt.Color.decode(Color.java:729)
at org.geoserver.wms.legendgraphic.LegendUtils.color(LegendUtils.java:494)
at org.geoserver.wms.legendgraphic.LegendUtils.color(LegendUtils.java:514)
```

In GeoServer when I check the style directly in the GUI, this is what I see:

```
name:  Test Style
title: test style description
abstract: Used for testing
feature-styles:
 - rules:
  - title: raster
    scale: [min, max]
    symbolizers:
     - raster:
         opacity: 1.0
         color-map:
           type: values
           entries:
           - ['java.awt.Color[r=226,g=3,b=116]', 1.0, 1, lorem ipsum]
```

As can be seen in this example, the #e20374 color code is converted java.awt.Color[r=226,g=3,b=116], which of course can't be converted to a number.

**Question:**

1. What causes this wrong conversion?
2. What needs to be done to ensure that the correct number string is applied?

Comment: what do you get if you request a correct style through the REST API?

Comment: @iant what do you mean by 'request a correct style'. When I request the style via REST , then I get the an sld style exactly as the above with ´<sld:ColorMapEntry color="java.awt.Color[r=226,g=3,b=116]"´. The probelm seems to occur during convertion from yaml to sld.

Comment: I mean if you look at a style that works like population

Comment: Then we get the following: ´<sld:ColorMapEntry color="#FFFFFF" opacity="1.0" quantity="3869" label="Max."/></sld:ColorMap>´

Comment: and if you request it in ysld?

Comment: This is what I get when I request a yaml format ´- ['java.awt.Color[r=226,g=3,b=116]', 1.0, 1, lorem ipsum]´

Comment: So if the color is correctly typed i.e color="#FFFFFF" in the sld, then all is ok, however in cases where the color is wrongly typed, eg java.awt.Color[r=226,g=3,b=116, then we get an error. When we however manually edit the color property value in the geoserver web UI, then the problem is solved. BUT, this manual editing is exactly what we dont want to do after we apply a style to a layer.